# Forward remote port to remote host

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding

Using SSH, I can do something like `ssh -R 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 remote.host` to forward my local port 8080 to a remote host.

I'm trying to do something similar, but the port I need to forward is on a remote machine that I lack shell access to. For example, if the remote machine is located at `192.168.1.10`, I'd like `remote.host:8080` to be coming from `192.168.1.10:8080`.

Can this be done with plain SSH? At some point I'll simplify this by just doing a port forward in the router, but I won't have that level of access for a few days.

Comment: So what kind of access do you have on the remote machine?

Comment: I don't have any remote access to the remote machine. The only service it makes available is an HTTP server on port 8080.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Can you confirm or correct: you have three computers, let's call them *webserver* (`192.168.1.10`), which you have no ssh access to, but has a webserver running on it; *external* which you have ssh access to, and want the webserver available through; and *local* which is your computer. You want to be able to go to `http://external` and get tunnelled to the webserver.

Comment: That's correct. n.st's answer is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have shell access to another server on the same network, you can connect to `secondserver` via SSH and use it to tunnel all connections to your local port 8080 to port 8080 of the camera (IP `192.168.1.10`):

```
ssh -L 8080:192.168.1.10:8080 secondserver
```

Comment: This looks right, and I'd tried this earlier since it's how I interpreted the man page as well. However, while `curl http://192.168.1.10:3306/` gets a response, `ssh -L 3306:192.168.1.10:3306 remote.host` followed by `curl http://127.0.0.1:3306` on the remote machine gets `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`.

Comment: Using `-L` opens a socket on your **local** system, so you'll need (or rather, be able to) run `curl` on the machine from which you have connected to `remote.host`.

Comment: That's right; I always get -L and -R confused. Using -R works perfectly, and I'm not sure why it didn't when I tried it before posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run an ssh client on `192.168.1.10`, then it's easy. With the standard ssh command-line tool there's an `-L` option, which does the reverse of `-R` - it forwards traffic from a local port to a port accessible from the ssh server.

If `192.168.1.10` is a Windows computer, I'd recommend PuTTY, where you can set up these network tunnels through the Settings menu.

Comment: The remote host is a camera that runs a small web server on top of something FreeRTOS-based. It doesn't "officially" support shell access, which I'd need to run SSH. I've heard there are firmware hacks that could get me to a shell, but that's more work and potential risk than I'd like to take.

Comment: Right, I'd got the wrong end of the stick. I'll try again if I can get my head round what is needed.